# ActiveX fails to instantiate in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, activex, atl, internet-explorer-11

I have a custom ATL based activeX object, which worked well with IE9 and IE10 running on Windows 7. But with IE11 it does not render. IE11 does not even load the activeX.
If I go to the dev tools console and set the rendering mode as 10 or 9, the control is rendered. But the moment I switch to Edge, the control stops being rendered.

Has anything changed in the way ActiveX is rendered in IE11.

Here is the HTML fragment that instantiates the object:

```
<OBJECT ID="CustomControl" CLASSID="CLSID:9009C2CB-4BD2-4D25-A613-5EA9CF70A883" width=100% height=100%>
    <span style="color: red">ActiveX control failed to load!</span> 
</OBJECT>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No... I have not spent much time on this. For a workaround I set the rendering mode to ie 10 mode which is less than ideal

Comment: Does your control use scripting? behaviors?
document.selection and showpopup and some other methods were removed from IE11... use 'standards' methods (getSelection / popup divs) instead...